# Conversion between time string and second value

Tags: matlab

I am playing around with the conversion between the time string and the value in second in MATLAB. However, I notice this inconsistency.

```
startTime = '00:19:00';
N = 15; % minutes
% convert it to the value in sec
startSec = datenum(startTime, 'hh:mm:ss');
% N minutes passed
endSec = startSec+60*N;
% convert it back to the string format
endTime = datestr(endSec, 'hh:mm:ss');
```

I am expecting my `endTime` to be `'00:34:00'`, but it turns out to be `'00:12:00'`.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised your code works at all, because the format strings you passed to [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) are invalid; they need to be uppercase.

Second problem is your assumption that `datenum` converts the first argument into seconds and returns that value. From the documentation linked above:

> `DateNumber = datenum(DateString)` converts date strings to serial date numbers. ...
>
> A serial date number represents the whole and fractional number of
>   days from a fixed, preset date (January 0, 0000).

So you need to convert your time offset value also to a `DateNumber` before adding it to the first result. Here's a fixed version of your code

```
startTime = '00:19:00';
N = 15; % minutes

% convert it to the value in sec
startSec = datenum(startTime, 'HH:MM:SS');

% N minutes passed
endSec = startSec + datenum(sprintf('00:%02d:00', N), 'HH:MM:SS');

% convert it back to the string format
endTime = datestr(endSec, 'HH:MM:SS');
```

Comment: How stupid I am and how awesome this answer is! Danke! Thanks!

Comment: The only part that needs to be upper case is `MM` to disambiguate minutes from months. `hh:MM:ss` is just fine for MATLAB's `datenum`.

Answer (score 2):

[detenum](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) does not return seconds. Instead, it returns:

> the whole and fractional number of days from a fixed, preset date
>   (January 0, 0000).

```
    startTime = '00:19:00';
    N = 15; % minutes
    % convert it to the value in sec
    startSec = datenum(startTime, 'HH:MM:SS');

    startSec = startSec * 24*60*60; % get seconds

    % N minutes passed

    endSec = startSec+60*N;
    % convert it back to the string format
    endTime = datestr(endSec / (24*60*60), 'HH:MM:SS');

    % will result in 
    %endTime = 00:34:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
'HH:MM:SS'
```

is your desired datestring (mm is months). Secondly, datenum doesn't return seconds, it returns days passed from year zero.